# Can radio communications be fully disabled in a Tesla?

Tags: electronics, tesla

Can radio communications be fully disabled in Tesla vehicles like the Model S ?

I guess this question has two parts: software disablement and hardware disablement as follows:

(1) Software disablement. Are you able to "turn off" any and all radio transmissions that the car might try to make using the dash control panel? How reliable is that deactivation?

(2) Hardware disablement. Computers can have WiFi and other radio capabilities either on a pluggable board, or built in to the motherboard. In the Tesla's case, is it easy to find and remove such modules, thus totally deactivating radio communications from the car, or are the modules built in to the motherboard, or otherwise hidden or hard to remove?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but [this blog post](https://blog.lookout.com/blog/2015/08/07/hacking-a-tesla/) has some interesting information on it.

Answer (score 1):

This is directly from:  https://forums.tesla.com/en_CA/forum

> If you don't trust Tesla you would have to get someone to disconnect the cellular antennas. No doubt the car would run, but you'd lose so many of the features of the car such as:

- Software updates that fix bugs and add features.
- Real-time traffic info for the NAV.
- Slacker and TuneIn radio.
- Remote access to find your car and turn on the climate control before you get in.
- The ability to unlock and drive your car using just your cell phone and password (if enabled).
- A web browser, though its slow and limited.
- The ability to monitor other's (family members or service personnel) use of your car.

  https://www.teslamotors.com/about/legal#privacy-statement

And here's what they say about hacking the car: https://www.teslamotors.com/about/legal#security-vulnerability-reporting...

/forums/can-you-disconnect-tesla-internet